# Streambuilder does not work when i wrap it with a widget

Tags: flutter, mobile, firebase-authentication

I am trying to add a custom navbar to all of my pages. StreamBuilder works fine now but when I wrap the streambuilder with scaffold in order to include navbar, the ui does not change and the app does not do authentication events.

mainpage.dart (this version works fine)

```
class _MainPageState extends State<MainPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<User?>(  
      stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        // user is logged in
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return HomePage();
        }
        // user is not logged in
        else {
          return AuthPage();
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

mainpage.dart(when i wrap streambuilder with scaffold)

```
class _MainPageState extends State<MainPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
    body: StreamBuilder<User?>(
      stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        // user is logged in
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return HomePage();
        }
        // user is not logged in
        else {
          return AuthPage();
        }
      },
    ),
    bottomNavigationBar: Navbar2(),
    );
  }
}
```

Strambuilder does not navigate to homepage or authpage when it is wrapped with scaffold

Comment: Don't create the stream in the stream: parameter of the StreamBuilder (don't do this: `stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges()`).

Comment: @RandalSchwartz thx but what problem does it cause and what is the proper way of doing it??

Comment: Easiest to point you at my video I made about that a few years ago: https://youtu.be/sqE-J8YJnpg  and yes, I've gotten to use that video hundreds of times. :)

Comment: @RandalSchwartz thanks for helping, also liked the video :)